# Can't Render Data in React.js / Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, render

everyone.

I'm trying to iterate data I'm submitting in my React/Redux project. However, it is undefined. This data should be rendered below its Podcast, as it is their episodes.

```
import EpisodesContainer from '../containers/EpisodesContainer'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Podcast = ({id, title, image_format, website, history}) => {

    // debugger 
    return (
        <div>
            <div key={id}>
                    <h2>{title}</h2>
                    <Link to={`/podcasts/${id}`}><img id={`podcast-${id}`} src={image_format ? image_format.url : process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/public/noimage.jpeg'} width={300} height={300} alt={"podcast"} /></Link>
                    <p>{website}</p>
            </div>
            {(!!history && history.location.pathname === `/podcasts/${id}`) ? <EpisodesContainer podcast={{id, title, image_format, website}} /> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Podcast;
```

This is the episode component file.

```
const Episodes = (props) => {
    // debugger 
    return (
        <div>
            {props.episodes && props.episodes.map(episode => 
                <div key={episode.id}>
                    <h3>{episode.name}</h3>
                    <iframe src={episode.spotify_link} width="100%" height="232" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                </div>     
            )}     
        </div>
    )     
}
        
export default Episodes
```

I went as far as debugging in the Episode Container and this.props.podcast.episode is returning undefined. Is there any advice regarding this? Again, they are stored in the backend and Redux but they are not rendered even in the console. Here's the Episodes Container file for reference.

```
import React from 'react'
import EpisodeInput from '../components/EpisodeInput'
import Episodes from '../components/Episodes'

class EpisodesContainer extends React.Component {
    
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                < EpisodeInput />
                < Episodes episodes={this.props.podcast && this.props.podcast.episodes} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default EpisodesContainer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass episodes from the `Podcast` to `EpisodesContainer`.
podcast contains the following values.

```
{id, title, image_format, website}
```

You need to pass episodes as well from the `Podcast` in `podcast`.